# How to parse and flatten nested JSON API response into tabular format

Tags: python, json, dictionary, flatten, json-normalize

JSON structure:

```
{
    "help": "https://data.boston.gov/api/3/action/help_show?name=datastore_search_sql",
    "success": true,
    "result": {
        "records": [
            {
                "latitude": "42.38331999978103",
                "property_type": "Residential 1-family",
                "neighborhood": "Charlestown",
                "description": "Improper storage trash: res",
                "year built": "1885",
                "_full_text": "'-11':2 '-23':3 '-71.06920000136572':29 '00':4,5,6 '02129':16 '1':26 '107':13 '1885':23 '201340000':19 '2017':24 '2022':1 '2129':18 '42.38331999978103':28 'baldwin':14 'charlestown':17 'enforcement':7 'family':27 'improper':9 'lia':20 'res':12 'residential':25 'ryan':21 'st':15 'storage':10 'trash':11 'v':22 'violations':8",
                "longitude": "-71.06920000136572",
                "owner": "LIA RYAN V",
                "address": "107 Baldwin St, 02129",
                "date": "2022-11-23T00:00:00",
                "violation_type": "Enforcement Violations",
                "_id": 1,
                "year remodeled": "2017",
                "parcel": "201340000",
                "zip_code": "2129"
            },
            {
                "latitude": "42.32762329872878",
                "property_type":
            ...}
       ],
        "fields": [
            {
                "type": "int4",
                "id": "_id"
            },
            {
                "type": "tsvector"...
            }
        ],
        "sql": "SELECT * from \"dc615ff7-2ff3-416a-922b-f0f334f085d0\" where date >= '2022-11-23'"
    }
}
```

Received as API response from Boston.gov website:

```
 response = requests.request('GET', 'https://data.boston.gov/api/3/action/datastore_search_sql?sql=SELECT%20*%20from%20%22dc615ff7-2ff3-416a-922b-f0f334f085d0%22%20where%20date%20%3E=%20%272022-11-23%27')
```

So 5 top-level keys, but I only care about getting the result.records into a tabular format

Keys from relevant dict (result.records):

```
json_data['result']['records'][0].keys()
dict_keys(['latitude', 'property_type', 'neighborhood', 'description', 'year built', '_full_text', 'longitude', 'owner', 'address', 'date', 'violation_type', '_id', 'year remodeled', 'parcel', 'zip_code'])
```

The closest I have gotten is 1x52 dataframe using the flatten_json module's flatten(), however that just has each results.records dict in a separate column.

```
0   ...                                                 51
0  {'latitude': '42.38331999978103', 'property_ty...  ...  {'latitude': '42.38306999993893', 'property_ty...
```

Previous attempt using json_normalize (twice)

```
with open(extracted_data_fn) as json_file:
    # store file data in object
    json_data = json.load(json_file)
    print (json_data)

# using flatten_json module
flat_json = flatten_json.flatten(json_data)
df_flat = pd.DataFrame(flat_json, index = range(len(flat_json)))

df = pd.json_normalize(json_data)
df_result_records = pd.json_normalize(df['result.records'])
df_result_records
```

My preferred output would be the keys as columns and each value as a cell in the row.

Any thoughts on how to achieve this? Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

just use:

```
json_data= response.json()
df=pd.json_normalize(json_data['result']['records'])

df

|    |   latitude | property_type        | neighborhood   | description                 |   year built | _full_text                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           |   longitude | owner      | address               | date                | violation_type         |   _id |   year remodeled |       parcel |   zip_code |
|---:|-----------:|:---------------------|:---------------|:----------------------------|-------------:|:-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|------------:|:-----------|:----------------------|:--------------------|:-----------------------|------:|-----------------:|-------------:|-----------:|
|  0 |    42.3833 | Residential 1-family | Charlestown    | Improper storage trash: res |         1885 | '-11':2 '-23':3 '-71.06920000136572':29 '00':4,5,6 '02129':16 '1':26 '107':13 '1885':23 '201340000':19 '2017':24 '2022':1 '2129':18 '42.38331999978103':28 'baldwin':14 'charlestown':17 'enforcement':7 'family':27 'improper':9 'lia':20 'res':12 'residential':25 'ryan':21 'st':15 'storage':10 'trash':11 'v':22 'violations':8 |    -71.0692 | LIA RYAN V | 107 Baldwin St, 02129 | 2022-11-23T00:00:00 | Enforcement Violations |     1 |             2017 |   2.0134e+08 |       2129 |
|  1 |    42.3276 | Ellipsis             | nan            | nan                         |          nan | nan                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  |    nan      | nan        | nan                   | nan                 | nan                    |   nan |              nan | nan          |        nan |
```

Comment: Belated thank you - can't believe how simple it was.

Comment: Apologies, I do not have enough rep to do so. I will return when I do however!

Comment: You don't need rep to accept the answer. Simply press the gray tick mark to the left of the answer :)